# how to access function variable in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, mongoose, anonymous

I have a function as

```
 var emailExists = function (email) {
   mongoose.model('User', UserSchema).
    count({
        email: email
    }, function (err, count) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        return count;// how can i return this count
    });
 };
```

in another function i call emailExists

```
 var total = emailExists(email)
 console.log(total); // this gives undefined now
```

How can i get the return value from the anonymous function

EDIT:
After adding callbacks from suggestions below

```
var emailNotExists = function (email, _callback) {
 mongoose.model('User', UserSchema).
    count({
        email: email
    }, function (err, count) {
        if (err)
            return _callback(err, null);
        return _callback(null, ((count == 0) ? true : false));
    });
};
```

Function where it is called

```
   UserSchema.path('email').validate(function (email) {
   // I need to return true or false value from this function
   // on true the validation will success
   // on false "Email is registered" message will get fired
   emailNotExists(email, function (err, total) {

       // I can retrieve the True/false value here           
       console.log(total);
   });
  }, 'Email is registered');
```

Comment: Is `mogoose.model` an asynchronous function? If so, anything that depends on the result of the callback function has to be done _in_ the callback.

Comment: @Barmar please see my edited question. I hope I am clear this time.

Comment: Your first `return _callback(count)` is missing an argument to the callback.

Comment: @Barmar edited. I just want to return true/false from the emailNotExists() call in UserSchema.path.validate function. How can I do that

Comment: If you know what "asynchronous" means, it should be obvious why that can't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in a callback function:

```
var emailExists = function (email, _callback) {
   mongoose.model('User', UserSchema).
    count({
        email: email
    }, _callback);
 };
```

Then access the variable as follows:

```
emailExists(email, function(err, total) {
    console.log(total);
});
```

Comment: In my opinion, too much overhead for what he wants to do

Comment: But it's the correct approach. If the callback is asynchronous, you can't access the result immediately.

Comment: @leblma - not too much overhead imo, and better than creating a global variable as you have suggested ( imo ). Here everything is contained.

Comment: @leblma - Too much overhead? What does that even mean?

Comment: @MWay There's a much simpler way to do this, global variable. The code is more clean this way.

Comment: @leblma - No that idea is far from clean. Do you know if the `count()` function is or will ever be asynchronous? Callback functions keep it clean by containing everything.

Comment: @Mway Yes I know it cauz I'm god.

Comment: @MWay Doing callback is the right way. please see the edited question.

Comment: @MWay Accepting since your answer led me to right direction and answered my original question

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var total;
var emailExists = function (email) {
   mongoose.model('User', UserSchema).
    count({
        email: email
    }, function (err, count) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        total = count;
    });
 };
```

Then you can access it:
    console.log(total);

Comment: @Sami That's probably cause you forgot to mention that count is asynchronous.

Comment: @leblma sorry for not mentioning the async functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var emailExists = function (email) {
 var result;
   mongoose.model('User', UserSchema).
    count({
        email: email
    }, function (err, count) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        result =count;// how can i return this count
    });
  return result;
 };
```

Comment: This won't work if `mongoose.model` runs asynchronously, as I suspect it does.

Comment: @kjana83 this doesn't work cause the function is asynchronous